# Are there drinking water fountains airside at London City Airport?

Tags: airports, london, airport-terminals, tap-water, lcy

When flying, I normally take an empty water bottle (or two) with me. To comply with liquid regulations at security, I ditch any remaining water landside just before or after checkin, pass through security with completely empty water bottles (which is allowed), then find a water fountain air-side to refill it. I then have (for free!) water for the flight.

I can't see anything on the [London City Airport website](http://www.londoncityairport.com/), either in text or on the map, about water fountains. I couldn't spot any either from a quick look in person, but I know that while London's Heathrow Airport has them they're not always the easiest to spot without directions, so it isn't impossible I missed them.

So, are there drinking water fountains air-side at London City Airport, and if so, where?

Answer (score 13):

Having checked with both the information desk in the airport, and emailing the airport, the answer is sadly no. Their response was:

> Thank you for your comments about drinking water fountains.
>
> Lack of suitable locations has been the main issue why we have not
>   introduced the facilities, however, we have started a terminal development
>   program and are looking at making changes that best meets the passenger's
>   needs.

However, there is a workaround to get water for free:

> If you need water please approach any of our restaurants in
>   departures and a member of staff will happily assist you.

I can confirm that the Caffe Nero near gates 21-24 have cups and a water jug out for all to avail themselves of, and the City Grill were perfectly happy to give me a glass of iced water (even offered a slice of lemon!) when I wasn't ordering anything else from them. I haven't tried asking to get a waterbottle filled though, will have to look into that on another trip.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that tap water in the UK is safe to drink, so if you can't find a restaurant, bathroom taps would work.

Comment: Only cold water taps with no storage tank are safe to drink from, so only some bathroom taps will work, not all

Comment: Cold water taps is safe to drink unless otherwise stated in the UK. But London tap water is very clayey and not very pleasant to drink if you are used to more spring like tap water.

Comment: Most taps to wash your hands in UK airports have lukewarm water, with no option to set the temperature. Not what you want in your water bottle. The option of getting some water at a restaurant helps when desperate for a drink, it is not a good option to fill your water bottle before a flight.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a 2020 info: filtered water refill station located at gates 7&8, and all food and drink places are happy to refill your water bottle on request :)